# Video Frame Skipping Issues During Chunking and Uploading in React Native App

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

To create a social media platform like `Instagram` and `Facebook`, we have incorporated the functionality for users to upload `reels-style` videos. To enhance the viewing experience, we have implemented a strategy to segment these videos and upload them to the backend.

To achieve this, we have employed the `ffmpeg-kit-react-native` and `rn-fetch-blob` libraries to segment videos efficiently. We've written an asynchronous function, chunkVideo, which chunks the input video file into segments of a specified duration. Here's a snippet of the code:

```js
async function chunkVideo(inputVideoFile, fileName, segmentDuration = 3) {
try {
  // Define the cache directory path
  const cacheDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir;
  const outputTSFilePattern = `${cacheDir}/${fileName}_video%d.ts`;
  await FFmpegKit.execute(
   `-i ${inputVideoFile} -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time ${segmentDuration} -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename ${outputTSFilePattern} -f hls ${cacheDir}/index.m3u8`,
  );
} catch (err) {
  logEvent("chunkVideoError", {error: err?.message});
  errorToast(err, true);
  }
}
```

While this approach works well for segmenting videos, we encountered an issue where some frames are skipping during the chunking process, leading to a compromised viewing experience for the end-users.

How to mitigate the frame skipping problems?

Comment: Are you able to elaborate, when you say some frames are skipping during the chunking process - do you mean: a) the video chunks that you create have missing frames in them, or b) while the video chunking is happening, the app is skipping frames and causing a jittery / laggy UI experience?

Comment: @KTas, Because of this, a) the video chunks that you create have missing frames in them.

Comment: TBH if it were me, I'd probably write some native code in Swift & Kotlin to handle this part of the operation if unable to quickly resolve the issue of the missing frames. Splitting videos into small chunks is very trivial in Swift and Kotlin, you also have more fine-grain control of your threads there in the native world - so you can manage the performance of the device better whilst the chunking is happening.